# How do I implement SpecFlow Hooks for multipart when conditions?

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I am developing an automated payment processing service for our enterprise.  We are trying to implement spec flow and we have successfully done that for 1 when condition

```
Scenario Outline: Stub matches NEXT oldest outstanding bill
    Given I have a group with the following bills:
        | Id     | Due Date   | Status               | Amount Due |
        | Bill A | 9/14/2011  | <Oldest Bill Status> | 1100.00    |
        | Bill B | 10/14/2011 | Unpaid               | 1200.00    |
        | Bill C | 11/14/2011 | Unpaid               | 1300.00    |
    When a stub is received that matches 'Bill B'
            And the Payment Amount is <Payment Amount>
    Then the allocation result should <Allocation Result>
            And Review should <Review>
Examples:
    | Oldest Bill Status | Allocation Result | Review       | Payment Amount |
    | Reconciled         | Allocate to Bill  | not required | 1200.00        |

[When(@"a stub is received that matches '(.*)'")]
        public void WhenAStubIsReceivedThatMatches(string billKeyName)
        {
           // Method
            }
```

I am not sure how to change the hooks to handle both condition prior to executing the result step.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to have one When statement.

Some options include:

```
 When a stub is received that matches 'Bill B' for <Payment Amount>
```

and therefore:

```
[When(@"a stub is received that matches '(.*)' for ([\d\.]*)")]
public void WhenAStubIsReceivedThatMatches(string billKeyName, decimal amount)
{
    // create stub and "recieve" it
}
```

OR

```
 Given ...etc...
 And I have a stub is received that matches 'Bill B' for <Payment Amount>
 When I receive the stub
```

... because the stub itself isn't the object being tested, it's background data and can sensibly be created as part of your givens.

Comment: In this test the stub is not being tested.  I was hoping to be able to reuse the when for the original tests but it seems that will not be possible(or at least not how I should do it).

Answer (score 1):

Having more than one When-clause is discourged... I think you can understand (and explain) why, since your asking this question. It's quite hard to put several actions together, since they depend on each other.

Try to write your specifications with a simple When-clause and rather write different scenarios to describe the different ways you interact.

So for your scenario, try to find out what is the important state-shift that take place to in order to go from the Given-state to the Then-state, if you like.

This is a little recipe I have found useful for writing scenarios

- First write a short title
- then start to fill out the Then-steps. What are you going to end up in? What asserts are needed?
- Then write the When-steps. How do I get to the Then-state
- Then write the Given-steps. What context is needed before I can get perform the When-clause?
- Now revise the title and see if you have come up with other scenarios that is needed to be taken under consideration.

I was at a course with Gjoko Adzic a few weeks back and picked up lots of tips like this. [Read about it here](http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/11/what-i-learned-from-from-user-stories.html)

Comment: *I think you can understand (and explain) why* - Actually other than it may not be possible to code I am not sure why.  This seems like a valid solution for a matrix to matrix compare as is being required by our business rules.  Rewriting the given then when to limit it to a single when reduces our ability to reuse the code and  the readability of the feature file.  I can do this with a multi-part reg-ex for the when clause but the cucumber blogs considered this an anti pattern.

Comment: @Chad well it was the complexity to code that I was referring to. Matrix-to-matrix rules sounds quite complex - can Gherkin tables help you with that? Check Scenario Outline for example (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines)

Comment: The payment amount is actually in the examples table(along with the Result and Review statuses. The business rules are complex this is the simplest way to define them.  My thought is i can set up the request with the When hooks, then execute the request after the when and then reuse the when set up for tests where i do not need the payment amount.  Is this not possible?

Comment: I updated the question with a bit more of the context of the scenario if that helps.

Comment: Oh man - that looks pretty complicated. But as I can see it, it seems like Bill A and C doesn't come into play? Couldn't the you just write a scenario that just matches 'Bill B' with a When-statement like "When stub for 'Bill B' is received with payment amount <Payment Amount> is recieved"?

Comment: Bill c does not come into play for this Scenerio but it does for others.  The business rules are based on the status of bill A I simplified the table to just have the one row.  I am trying to include the stub for bill b in the given part and then the payment amount for the when.  This may work and actually improve reusability.  It is complicated because the logic it is testing is complicated.